# Mule 4 - Using The Redis Connector as a Custom Object Store "Connection is no longer valid"

Tags: caching, redis, mule

I'm trying to use Redis as the backend for an object store for a Mule 4 project. I've followed the instructions [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/redis/redis-connector#use-the-redis-connector-as-a-custom-object-store), however I keep getting an error when the project is booting:

> Caused by: reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.DefaultMuleException: Obtained invalid connection from ObjectStore config 'ObjectStore_Config'.
>   Error Type: UNKNOWN.
>   Message: Connection is no longer valid

Here is a truncated view of my configuration:

```
<mule xmlns:redis="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/redis"
    xmlns:os="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os"
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mule-apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/os/current/mule-os.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/redis http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/redis/current/mule-redis.xsd">    

  ...

  <os:config name="ObjectStore_Config" doc:name="ObjectStore Config" doc:id="627a35b0-4b36-45e2-8ff6-fdd0eb9cb067">
    <redis:nonclustered-connection host="http://localhost:6379" />
  </os:config>

  <os:object-store name="Object_store" 
    config-ref="ObjectStore_Config"
    maxEntries="1"
    entryTtl="60"
    expirationInterval="10"
    expirationIntervalUnit="SECONDS"
    doc:name="Object store" 
    doc:id="bef9d4d3-0441-477c-a8b1-46626c95c9de" />  

  ...
</mule>
```

I'm running Redis from docker on my local machine:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
126faa8c33a7        redis:3.2.12        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 days ago          Up 5 days           0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   redis
```

I've verified in a separate project that I can use the redis connector to connect to this instance and get/set data.

Why would this connection no longer work for the ObjectStore configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I compared my project to the sample project provided by mule support [here](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-To-Use-Redis-As-Custom-Object-Store-Reference-In-Mule-4) and found that I needed to add the `<redis:redis-config>` element, as well as split my `host` attribute on the `redis:nonclustered-connection` nested within `os:config` to be both `host` and `port`:

```
<os:config name="ObjectStore_Config">
  <redis:nonclustered-connection host="localhost" port="6379"/>
</os:config>

<redis:redis-config name="Redis_Redis" doc:name="Redis Redis" >
  <redis:nonclustered-connection />
</redis:redis-config>
```